# Modalbox plugin error in Grails application

Tags: grails, plugins, gsp

I have a problem on runtime using modalbox plugin with Grails 2.4.4. I'm getting the following trace error:

```
2017-01-31 18:05:59,066 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - PowerAssertionError occurred when processing request: [GET] /Ghertor/
assert f.delete()
       | |
       | false
       /var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/Ghertor/grails-resources/plugins/modalbox-0.4/js/modalbox. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : main
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <modalbox:modalIncludes>: assert f.delete()
       | |
       | false
       /var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/Ghertor/grails-resources/plugins/modalbox-0.4/js/modalbox
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <modalbox:modalIncludes>: assert f.delete()
       | |
       | false
       /var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/Ghertor/grails-resources/plugins/modalbox-0.4/js/modalbox
    at gsp_ghertor_layoutsmain_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(gsp_ghertor_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:45)
    at gsp_ghertor_layoutsmain_gsp.run(gsp_ghertor_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:58)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: Assertion failed: 

assert f.delete()
       | |
       | false
       /var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/Ghertor/grails-resources/plugins/modalbox-0.4/js/modalbox

    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.makeFileForURI(ResourceProcessor.groovy:587)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceMeta.beginPrepare(ResourceMeta.groovy:262)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:667)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_getResourceMetaForURI_closure11.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:530)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.util.ResourceMetaStore.getOrCreateAdHocResource(ResourceMetaStore.groovy:98)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.getResourceMetaForURI(ResourceProcessor.groovy:510)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib.resolveLinkUriToUriAndResource(ResourceTagLib.groovy:565)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib$_closure11.doCall(ResourceTagLib.groovy:592)
    at ModalboxTagLib$_closure2.doCall(ModalboxTagLib.groovy:18)
    ... 10 more
```

I'm including the modalbox library in my main gsp layout: main.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
        <g:javascript src="util.js"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
        <calendar:resources lang="es" theme="blue2"/>
        <g:layoutHead/> 
        <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
        **<modalbox:modalIncludes />**
...
```

What's happening?. Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: looks like the `resource plugin` can not delete some file. Make sure your grails process hat permissions to do that

Comment: Thanks!. It's strange because in local it's working fine.